# Show row on mysql with this case

Tags: mysql

I have rows in my table like this

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | cid   | number | value        | date                |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
|  2 |     1 |     55 | two to one   | 2020-04-19 11:25:52 |
|  2 |     9 |     56 | two to nine  | 2020-04-19 11:26:04 |
|  1 |     2 |     57 | one to two   | 2020-04-19 11:27:02 |
|  9 |     2 |     58 | nine to two  | 2020-04-19 11:28:01 |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
```

What is the sql code to show like this

```
+----+-------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
| id | cid   | number | value        | date                |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
|  1 |     2 |     57 | one to two   | 2020-04-19 11:27:02 |
|  9 |     2 |     58 | nine to two  | 2020-04-19 11:28:01 |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+---------------------+
```

That is mean just show latest row and make the `id` with `cid` is same like `id=1-cid=2` is same with `id=2-cid=1`. Anybody please help and i hope you are know what i mean. Thank you so much

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Please leave data in text form, not an image. It is much more useful as text to users who are trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a derived table to generate a list of latest date values for each combination of `id` and `cid` values, using [`LEAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to map (for example) `(1, 2)` to `(2, 1)`. This can then be `JOIN`ed to the original table to get the data for latest date:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.cid, t1.number, t1.value, t1.date
FROM data t1
JOIN (
  SELECT LEAST(id, cid) AS l_id, 
         GREATEST(id, cid) AS g_id,
         MAX(date) AS max_date
  FROM data
  GROUP BY l_id, g_id
) t2 ON t2.max_date = t1.date
    AND (t2.l_id = t1.id AND t2.g_id = t1.cid OR
         t2.l_id = t1.cid AND t2.g_id = t1.id)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
id  cid     number  value           date
1   2       57      one to two      2020-04-19T11:27:02Z
9   2       58      nine to two     2020-04-19T11:28:01Z
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c46304/1)